# How to get the first two words in a string Flutter

Tags: string, flutter

I have this string example: *Hello my name is*

And this is what I want to show: *Hello my*

What is the best practice to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split, then `take(2)` and then join them again:

```
  final src = 'Hello my name is';
  final result = src.split(' ').take(2).join(' ');
  print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to break down the sentence into a `List` of words :

```dart
String test = 'Hello my name is';

List<String> words = test.split(" ");
  
  
print('${words[0]} ${words[1]}');
```